# Surge CP overload but low CPU usage. Got log in issue on web application when it happens. why?

Tags: solaris, login, cpu, application

I am unable to login to solaris server via GUI mode. We have checked and found that the DB/oracle session was hung up. GUI was not  able to connect to Oracle DB . After clearing the hung counters from the DB by performing a DB stop start. Problem got solved.

I have faced this problem more than two times.

I am new in here. So, my query is, what will be its permanent solution?

Some basic investigation shows the CPU to be idle, lots of memory to be available, no swapping, no I/O.

Running prstat -L gives something like this:

```
  PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE  PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/LWPID      
21178 ipvk      869M   74M sleep   59    0   4:17:33 0.1% DynamicEngine/35
19334 root       96M   89M sleep    1    0   3:09:36 0.1% psmon/26
21178 ipvk      869M   74M sleep   59    0   3:22:57 0.1% DynamicEngine/36
 171 root       11M 9176K sleep    1    0   1:59:28 0.0% nscd/33
 22309 oracle   2617M 2444M sleep    1    0   2:24:22 0.0% oracle/1
27367 root     5720K 5704K cpu20   59    0   0:00:01 0.0% prstat/1
28050 oracle   2619M 2450M sleep    1    0   1:17:23 0.0% oracle/1
22288 oracle   2617M 2444M sleep    1    0   0:27:09 0.0% oracle/1
19354 oracle   2617M 2444M sleep    1    0   0:32:43 0.0% oracle/1
21532 oracle   2617M 2444M sleep   56    0   0:46:36 0.0% oracle/1
21178 ipvk      869M   74M sleep   50    0   0:36:23 0.0% DynamicEngine/27
21500 oracle   2617M 2448M sleep    1    0   0:35:34 0.0% oracle/1
18557 oracle    179M   54M sleep   13    0   0:44:40 0.0% java/286
18557 oracle    179M   54M sleep   59    0   0:40:31 0.0% java/245
 1122 root     1432K 1368K sleep   59    0   1:23:37 0.0% ei_check/1
 171 root       11M 9176K sleep   38    0   1:25:27 0.0% nscd/36
 1 root     2680K 1952K sleep    1    0   1:31:36 0.0% init/1
19994 oracle   2617M 2448M sleep   59    0   0:13:08 0.0% oracle/1
21838 oracle   2618M 2449M sleep   48    0   0:10:01 0.0% oracle/1
20717 ipvk       50M   18M sleep   59    0   0:12:28 0.0% tnameserv/5
21173 oracle   2618M 2449M sleep    1    0   0:19:15 0.0% oracle/1
21834 oracle   2618M 2449M sleep    1    0   0:11:38 0.0% oracle/1
21832 oracle   2618M 2449M sleep   46    0   0:09:34 0.0% oracle/1
21836 oracle   2618M 2445M sleep   48    0   0:15:18 0.0% oracle/1
Total: 462 processes, 1937 lwps, load averages: 0.72, 0.71, 0.71
```

I understand that CPU is mostly idle. 
Running vmstat 15 gives something like this:

```
 kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr m1 m1 m1 m5   in   sy   cs us sy id
 0 0 0 24716664 9547608 240 942 57 2 2 0 0 10  0  0  6 3940 12363 6742 1  1 98
 0 0 0 24554776 9394288 270 1496 0 0 0 0 0  1  0  1  5 3921 11370 6525 1  1 98
 0 0 0 24554648 9394224 169 525 0 1 0 0  0  1  0  0  6 3863 9764 6388  1  1 98
 0 0 0 24554176 9393912 179 676 0 1 1 0  0  2  0  0  6 3877 11137 6579 1  1 98
```

Running netstat -i 15 gives the following:

```
    input   e1000g    output       input  (Total)    output
packets errs  packets     errs  colls  packets errs  packets errs  colls 
602510508 0     626130152 0     0      1313898201 0     1411600525 0     0     
  5064    0       5253    0     0      10962   0     11766   0     0     
  4892    0       5095    0     0      10794   0     11580   0     0     
  4917    0       5077    0     0      10928   0     11744   0     0
```

Running swap -l gives this:

```
swapfile             dev  swaplo blocks   free
/dev/md/dsk/d60     85,60     16 33560432 33560432
```

Running swap -s gives this:

```
total: 4719720k bytes allocated + 798856k reserved = 5518576k used, 24555352k available
```

Is this a application fix issue? Kindly help to solve this issue.

Client statistics: nfsstat -c

```
Client rpc:
Connection oriented:
calls      badcalls   badxids    timeouts   newcreds   badverfs   timers     
42020      0          0          0          0          0          0          
cantconn   nomem      interrupts 
0          0          0          
Connectionless:
calls      badcalls   retrans    badxids    timeouts   newcreds   badverfs   
73610      1          0          0          0          0          0          
timers     nomem      cantsend   
16         0          0
```

Client nfs:

```
calls     badcalls  clgets    cltoomany 
73610     1         73610     8         
Version 2: (73609 calls)
null      getattr   setattr   root      lookup    readlink  read      
0 0%      13 0%     0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      
wrcache   write     create    remove    rename    link      symlink   
0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      
mkdir     rmdir     readdir   statfs    
0 0%      0 0%      0 0%      73596 99% 
Version 3: (0 calls)
null        getattr     setattr     lookup      access      readlink    
0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        
read        write       create      mkdir       symlink     mknod       
0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        
remove      rmdir       rename      link        readdir     readdirplus 
0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        
fsstat      fsinfo      pathconf    commit      
0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        
Version 4: (0 calls)
null                compound            
0 0%                0 0%                
Version 4: (0 operations)
reserved            access              close               commit              
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
create              delegpurge          delegreturn         getattr             
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
getfh               link                lock                lockt               
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
locku               lookup              lookupp             nverify             
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
open                openattr            open_confirm        open_downgrade      
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
putfh               putpubfh            putrootfh           read                
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
readdir             readlink            remove              rename              
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
renew               restorefh           savefh              secinfo             
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
 setattr             setclientid         setclientid_confirm verify              
0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                0 0%                
write               
0 0%
```

Client nfs_acl:

```
Version 2: (1 calls)
null        getacl      setacl      getattr     access      getxattrdir 
0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        1 100%      0 0%        0 0%        
Version 3: (0 calls)
null        getacl      setacl      getxattrdir 
0 0%        0 0%        0 0%        0 0%
```

Network statistics for each file system
: netstat -m

```
streams allocation:
                                         cumulative  allocation
                      current   maximum       total    failures
streams                  1180      1520    45685867           0
queues                   2708      3072    56283358           0
mblk                   265325    276860 -1759227703           0
dblk                   265323    291455    98613018           0
linkblk                     5       169           9           0
syncq                      10       300       10698           0
qband                       1       127           2           0

52580 Kbytes allocated for streams data
```

Thanks

Wasila